# cpulimit not working correctly

Tags: linux, debian, cpu-usage

I'm using Debian Wheezy and cpulimit 1.7
I want to limit the cpu usage time of a process using `cpulimit`.

When I execute for example `cpulimit -p 1000 -l 40`, the message `Process 1000 detected` shows up. After that, nothing happens and I have to press Strg+C to stop it.

Anybody also encountered this problem or has a solution to that hang-up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's what it always looks like when you start cpulimit.

`cpulimit` works by continuously sending `SIGSTOP` and `SIGCONT` to the target process to limit it's cpu time. So the program in this case doesn't hang, it's doing it's job.

You can use the `-b` flag to start `cpulimit` in background mode if you don't want it to block the terminal.

Comment: How to 'release' the restriction? eg, If I want to restrict cpu usage for a processor while I run a more important task, but once the task is done, I want to release the earlier processor so that it's free to use more cpu as needed.